# SQL Server: convert string 'n', 'hh', 'd' to global variables n, hh and d

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, dateadd

We're using a very high level framework, called Instant Developer, where Date Parts are implemented as strings. Implementing an interface, I added to the library of my project the function `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )` from SQL Server. But when I call it, the generated code is, for example,

```
SELECT dateadd('n',90,CONVERT(datetime, DATEREQUEST+TIMEREQUEST))
FROM [Ergo].[dbo].[MANUTENZIONI]
where TICKETMANUTE = 17723
```

but SQL Server rises ax exception since the first parameter of `dateadd()` function is incorrect because it's not supposed to be a string but a global variable. Is there a way to convert it? Something like:

```
dateadd(case when 'n'='n' then n end, 90, CONVERT(datetime, DATEREQUEST+TIMEREQUEST))
```

Comment: why you can't generate `dateadd(n,90,CONVERT(datetime, DATEREQUEST+TIMEREQUEST))`?

Comment: As a workaround create wrapper functions `dateadd_N(int,datetime)`,`dateadd_D(int,datetime)`, ...

Comment: Because my framework won't let me... as I've written, date parts are implemented as strings. So If I call `dateAdd(Minutes,90,date)` that Minutes is translated into 'n'...

Comment: @Serg: that exactly what I did...I just wanted to have a unique functions because I already have too many functions...

Comment: Alternatively create `MyDateadd(varchar(5),int,datetime)` which checks first param and returns proper dateadd

Comment: @Serg thatcould be a solution...but n, hh and d what are exactly? integers?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper function which accepts varchar as a type of interval

```
create function myDateadd(@type varchar(5), @amount int, @dt datetime)
returns datetime
as
begin
return case @type
       when 'n' then dateadd(n, @amount, @dt)
       when 'd' then dateadd(d, @amount, @dt)
       -- ...
       end;
end
go

select dbo.myDateadd('n',60,getdate());
```